# Trying to cast rows to columns in r

Tags: r

I am trying to something very simple in R, transpose a data set so I can create a primary key for joining with other tables that have many values.

I've tried dcast and aggregate, and haven't gotten them to work.
Here's what my dataframe currently looks like
[Current R dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIjhy.jpg)

Here's what I would like it to look like:
[New R dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALLDw.jpg)

Comment: Please provide data as plain text not images, so users can easily copy/paste it.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: You can edit the question: paste the output from `dput(your_data_frame)`, or just paste the data frame with rows indented 4 spaces. If it's too long you can use `head(your_data_frame, n)` where n is number of lines, or `dput(head(your_data_frame, n))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can insere code in your post, so paste the code that create your data.frame, like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Make     = c('Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Chevy', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler'),
  DateSold = c('2017-07-01', '2017-08-01', '2017-10-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-01'),
  Amount   = c(30, 15, 25, 23, 22, 21) * 1e3
)
```

Now for your question, you can use the library **tidyverse** which have a lot of useful functions to manipulate data. You can execute the following code line by line in order to understand the different steps to arrive to the solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(-Make, key = Column, value = Value) %>%
  group_by(Make, Column) %>% 
  mutate(Count = 1:n()) %>% 
  unite(Column_count, Column, Count) %>%
  spread(Column_count, Value)

#   Make     Amount_1 Amount_2 Amount_3 DateSold_1 DateSold_2 DateSold_3
#   <fct>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
# 1 Chevy    23000    NA       NA       2017-01-01 NA         NA        
# 2 Chrysler 22000    21000    NA       2017-03-01 2017-04-01 NA        
# 3 Ford     30000    15000    25000    2017-07-01 2017-08-01 2017-10-01
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Think of validation one answer if it corresponds to your demand.

Answer (score 0):

Using reshape, you can do somithing like:

```
 reshape(transform(df,time=ave(Amount,Make,FUN=seq_along)),dir = 'wide',idvar='Make')

      Make DateSold.1 Amount.1 DateSold.2 Amount.2 DateSold.3 Amount.3
1     Ford 2017-07-01    30000 2017-08-01    15000 2017-10-01    25000
4    Chevy 2017-01-01    23000       <NA>       NA       <NA>       NA
5 Chrysler 2017-03-01    22000 2017-04-01    21000       <NA>       NA
```